# AAD B2C - No way to submit verification code to login on iOS simulator when Multi-factor authentication enabled

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

We are following [Azure AD B2C MFA documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-mfa) and found an issue with login on iOS simulator when MFA (multi-factor authentication) is enabled.

With MFA enabled, user is required to provide a phone number, then submit a verification code received via SMS to proceed the login process. The problem is after entering the code received from SMS in the in-app browser UI, nothing happens in the UI. I assume there should be a submit button (only a "Cancel" button) or the in-app browser should detect the code and automatically submit it to the server, but it seems to be missing.

I have not yet tried on this on real devices. But this issue completely blocks logging in from an iOS simulator.

Am I missing anything? Any help is appreciated.

[image: screenshot of the in-app browser verification code UI]

Comment: Have you tried to restart your IOS simulator? This display page is not complete.

Comment: @SunnySun I can reproduce this on multiple simulators, so I don't think it's a local simulator issue.

Comment: Was this resolved?

Comment: @Parakh, Not resolved.